[GSI_LOGGER]: Store credential failed
I'm new to google OAuth. I'm trying to store the credentials of a user, but i end up getting this error:
[GSI_LOGGER]: Store credential failed: {}

It seems like when the user signs in the with google button, it's working because I am receiving a JSON Web Token, and the button displays the user's email address and photo. But i can't seem to store the credentials properly.
Am i storing the credentials properly? Here is my code:
function onSignIn(responsePayload) {
    let cred = {id: responsePayload.sub, credential: responsePayload.credential};

    // Stores the credential using Google Identity Services
    google.accounts.id.storeCredential(cred);

    console.log("ID: " + responsePayload.sub);
    console.log('Full Name: ' + responsePayload.name);
    console.log('Given Name: ' + responsePayload.given_name);
    console.log('Family Name: ' + responsePayload.family_name);
    console.log("Image URL: " + responsePayload.picture);
    console.log("Email: " + responsePayload.email);

    // Redirect to the welcome page
    //window.location.href = '/welcome.html';

  }

window.handleCredentialResponse = (response) => {

        console.log("The response is >>>", response);

    function decodeJWTResponse(){
        const base64Url = response.credential.split('.')[1];
        const base64 = base64Url.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');
        const jsonPayload = decodeURIComponent(atob(base64).split('').map(function(c) {

            return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);

        }).join(''));

            return JSON.parse(jsonPayload);
    }

    const responsePayload = decodeJWTResponse(response.credential);

    console.log("ID: " + responsePayload.sub);
    console.log('Full Name: ' + responsePayload.name);
    console.log('Given Name: ' + responsePayload.given_name);
    console.log('Family Name: ' + responsePayload.family_name);
    console.log("Image URL: " + responsePayload.picture);
    console.log("Email: " + responsePayload.email);

    emailAddress = responsePayload.email;

    onSignIn(responsePayload);

}


and i am rendering the google button using html:
<div id="g_id_onload"
        data-client_id="{my-client-id}"
        data-context="signin"
        data-callback="handleCredentialResponse"
        data-ux_mode="popup"
        data-login_uri="{my-login-uri}"
        data-auto_prompt="false">
    </div>

    <div class="g_id_signin"
        data-type="standard"
        data-shape="rectangular"
        data-theme="outline"
        data-text="signin_with"
        data-size="large"
        data-logo_alignment="left">
    </div>



Any ideas why I am getting this error? Am i using  google.accounts.id.storeCredential() improperly? Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance and happy coding :)
